# Visual Studio Professional 2019 version 16.10.0 Can't open .sql files in SSDT project

Tags: visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools

Upgrade VS 2019 Professional to latest version 16.10.0. Open an existing SSDT project, double-click on any sql script file in the project, the file can't be opened in a tab window.

If the sql script defines a table, I can see the message: The design surface is loading. I can see the separator between design and script surfaces. If I drag the separator to resize the surfaces, the window gets refreshed and the script will open correct.

If the sql script defines a view or stored procedure, I only see blank tab window. i don't see any messages.

If I restart the VS2019, the previous opened scripts are working fine. But still the same problem whenever I want to open a script which is not opened before the restart.

Comment: Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to notify the people that can fix a bug like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VS 2019 Community 16.10, I can open one SQL file at a time. So if you shut all your open SQL files, you should be able to get a single one open.
Note: even uninstalling VS and starting with a clean install from the Microsoft site did not help.

Comment: While I agree this behavior should be reported to MS...this is helpful as a workaround until it is fixed. Confirmed in VS Enterprise.

Comment: Yes, it works for my VS 2019 Professional. It is a workaround, though still annoying. I already report the problem to MS.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a link to the root Microsoft tacked issue:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-Pro-16100---Tabs-do-not-/1434964

A quick work around to force the editor to re-draw: **resize the editor window** by dragging the solution explorer re-size bar.

Comment: This is the best workaround for me (resize the editor window)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to the MS discussion of this topic:
https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-see-content-of-sql-files/1437162?q=%5BVisual+Studio+2019+version+16.10%5D&ftype=problem&space=8&stateGroup=active&sort=newest

I was able to get two SQL windows open at the same time, though it is quite annoying: open both files and detach both from the documents frame so they float. Pick one and move it and size it where you want. The second will disappear as you do this, but never mind.

From the Window menu, select the second file. As you move it and size it, the first one will disappear.

Now select the invisible window from the Window menu. As long as you just move around and work within these two files, you should be able to keep them both open. So this is if you need to be looking at one view while you modify another, or some such thing.

For me, two is the limit. If I try three, only two will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug and seems to be fixed in the latest patch 16.10.2 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#--visual-studio-2019-version-16102-